# CSS file can be intentionally changed

Tags: css, security

I have been informed that that our CSS file can be intentionally changed by a bad actor on our web application. To give you a bit more context:

We are sending to our clients emails containing a link (see below) with personalized news. The 'Suggestions' site is a single page web application that lists news that are recommended to the user. The URL parameters are: lang, css, and proposals. The css is provided as URL parameter and will be loaded in addition to the default CSS.

https://somecompany.com/Suggestions/index.jsp?lang=en&css=https://www.test.com/style.css&proposals=Random Client ID //eg 12435

What type of attach is this? I am trying to find more info online in order to mitigate the issue but I am a bit lost. Can this be a "relative path overwrite" attack, or an "Unvalidated redirects" attack or "Web Parameter Tampering" attack or what else??

Than you in advance for your help

Comment: Your issue is a bit unclear. Are you saying that someone has changed and then saved the changes ? Things like chromes dev tools can allow users to make edits to HTML and CSS but it doesn't actually affect the file.

Comment: This is your page using the css parameter consciously...  I think this is a too specific hack to have a name. And I wonder how this is a risk. First of all, it's just CSS, and secondly, you only get the diffferent CSS if the url is wrong, so how did the CSS get in the URL in the first place?..

Answer (score 0):

Most probably someone meant XSS. Someone could inject code if you do not sanitize the css GET parameter (if this is the case this is a very serious security risk), or possibly make the client machine connect to a specific server ( the one specified in the CSS var ) this could be used for DDoS (but highly unlikely) or other reasons (this is not really a big risk).

Of course the most obvious attack would be to change how your page looks - it might not seem very useful, but for example changing the "remove account" button to be 100% width 100% height covering the page and transparent might not be what you would like ?

Answer (score 0):

"what type of attach is this?" It's a GET string. Whatever you pass to a web page via GET can be changed by the user easily. As easy as going to the URL bar at the top of the browser and changing the values there.

Conclusion, you shouldn't be passing CSS really at all, whether GET or POST. Second conclusion, if you don't want params to be user-editable (say by a bad actor) then use POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

There's two different potential issues at stake:

1. As @n00b mentioned, if the CSS isn't properly sanitised, then (like any GET / POST / WHATEVER parameter), then it can be used to inject malicious code into the site (such as rerouting the user to a similarly styled but malicious phishing site.
2. Alternately, eve if the CSS has been sanitised, it means an unfriendly user can share the link and pass in a random stylesheet - which may be used to deface the application (and hurl insults at your customers).

The other bit that worries me - your client IDs seem to be guessable. I only have to iterate through all of them to access other people's "personalized" news.